# Copy and Paste text from Dialogue Box in Applescript

Tags: copy, applescript, paste, dialog

i'm writing a script that needs to copy and paste text from an entry in a dialogue box

```
set query to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Text" default answer "" buttons {"Input", "Cancel"} default button 1)
query
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "c" using command down
    keystroke "v" using command down
end tell
```

when i run this script it copies and pastes "set query to text..."

**how can I copy the query that I entered ?** i'm going to paste the text somewhere else later but I need to figure out how to actually copy the text.  I was using keystroke query but that was taking a long time when the strings were long

Answer (score 0):

Use `set the clipboard`:

```
display dialog "" default answer ""
set the clipboard to text returned of result
```

If others get here searching for how to for example copy a long error message from a dialog shown by OS X, you can use Accessibility Inspector, which is in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/`.